WIN11 data decryption stuck and system frozen
I'm currently dealing with a significant problem on my ASUS laptop, which seems to stem from possible hardware malfunctions coupled with Windows 11 altering crucial settings without my permission. Here’s a breakdown of the situation and what I’ve attempted so far:
Issue Summary:

Automatic Encryption: Post-upgrade, Windows11 decided to encrypt my main system volume without asking my permission or even alerting me.
Decryption Attempt: I tried disabling the encryption, but the process froze at about 85%, and now my laptop freezes about a minute after startup. This occurs even on the login screen, rendering the system unusable.
Access to Data: I can’t access the encrypted volume via Ubuntu Live or other tools, as it appears encrypted and no passphrase is available.
TPM Lock: The volume seems to be locked with TPM, complicating matters further since there’s no recovery key available.

Technical Details:

System: ASUS Zenbook UX3402ZA, Windows 11 Home, Standalone Workstation
Encryption Status: BitLocker Drive Encryption partially disabled; main volume stuck at 13.6% decrypted.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Safe Mode: No success in any version via recovery mode.
Command Prompt: System checks and fixes through recovery mode command prompt were unsuccessful.
Alternate OS Access: Attempts to access the drive via Ubuntu Live and Hiren’s Boot were futile due to encryption.
BitLocker Management: Commands like manage-bde -changepassword, -add were ineffective.
System Reset: Attempted an OS reset while keeping files, but it stalled at 1%.
SFC: Tried to use sfc /scannow but didn't help.
SSD S.M.A.R.T. : I've also attempted to utilize the ASUS hardware diagnostic tool available through the BIOS to pinpoint the issue. However, it's proving to be unhelpful, particularly because it does not support testing for NVMe SSDs.
Enabling/Disabling Secure Boot: Enabling/Disabling this didn't help. It only disables the pin login.
Online Account Association Attempt: In hopes of syncing the encryption key to the cloud, I tried creating a new online Microsoft account on the Windows system. Despite rushing to set this up within the brief 40-second windows before resets, this approach failed to copy or retrieve the encryption key as anticipated.

Drive Details:

Volume C: Main OS volume, stuck in decryption with no key protectors found.
Volume D & E: Accessible and fully decrypted.

Possible Next Steps:

Disabling Decryption Service: Is there a way to halt the decryption process via services or another method? This might stabilize the system enough to allow data backup.
Alternate Access Methods: Any suggestions for accessing the encrypted drive from another OS or tool would be greatly appreciated.

I urgently need to retrieve my files from this encrypted volume before considering a complete format and OS reset. Any advice on how to proceed or if anyone has encountered a similar issue would be incredibly helpful.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
System and BitLocker Status:
OS Name: Microsoft Windows 11 Home
OS Version: 10.0.22631 N/A Build 22631
OS Configuration: Standalone Workstation
System Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
System Model: Zenbook UX3402ZA_UX3402ZA

manage-bde status:
Volume C: [OS]
Size: 414.54 GB
BitLocker Version: 2.0
Conversion Status: Decryption in Progress
Percentage Encrypted: 13.6%
Encryption Method: XTS-AES 128
Protection Status: Protection Off
Lock Status: Unlocked
Key Protectors: None Found

Volume D: [New Volume]
Size: 12.17 GB
BitLocker Version: None
Conversion Status: Fully Decrypted
Percentage Encrypted: 0.0%
Protection Status: Protection Off
Lock Status: Unlocked
Key Protectors: None Found

Volume E: [Drive]
Size: 48.83 GB
BitLocker Version: None
Conversion Status: Fully Decrypted

Looking forward to your insights and thank you for helping me navigate

The encryption key, is stored on the disk, but due to what I likely suspect is a failing drive the process to decrypt the drive will continue to run into problems.  Without a recovery key you can't use any tool or another Windows installation to decrypt the drive, even if you had the recovery key, it wouldn't helpful since you have no BitLocker protectors enabled.

@Ramhound Is there a way to get the key if it's on the drive? I am able to unlock the volume for about 40s after startup. Given this brief window, is there a way to retrieve the encryption key directly from the disk?

Is the account you logged into the computer with a Microsoft account, or local only? Microsoft stores the key off of the device prior to beginning encryption. I don't know if it removes that key when you begin the decryption process, but it may be worth trying what MS suggests here to get the key: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/finding-your-bitlocker-recovery-key-in-windows-6b71ad27-0b89-ea08-f143-056f5ab347d6

@music2myear it was a local account. I tried something similar in #9 with no luck.

Regrettably, the best bet is to restore from the last disk image -- it is unlikely that anyone can recover a partially encrypted disk, other than perhaps a state actor willing to devote a great deal of computer power for a long time.
